# Expected : but found . while calling JavaScript function from java

Tags: javascript, java

I am triying to call java script functon from java code but i am getting error as

```
Expected : but found .
      fs.writeFileSync(
        ^ in <eval> at line number 24 at column number 9
```

**Java script function**

```
var YamlToJson = function (name) {
var fs = require('fs'),
      Converter = require('openapi-to-postmanv2'),
      openapiData = fs.readFileSync('./output.json', { encoding: 'UTF8' })
    Converter.convert(
      { type: 'json', data: openapiData },
      {},
      (err, conversionResult) => 
      {
        if (!conversionResult.result) {
          console.log('Could not convert', conversionResult.reason)
        } else {
          fs.writeFileSync(
            'outputfile1.json',
            JSON.stringify(conversionResult.output[0].data),
          )
          console.log('The collection object is: ', conversionResult.output[0].data)
        }
      },
    )
}
```

**Java Code**

```
ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("nashorn");
        try {
          engine.eval(new FileReader("D:/CodeFactory/TestCases/GenerateTetsCases/src/main/java/com/GenerateTetsCases/GenerateTetsCases/YamlToJson.js"));
          Invocable invocable = (Invocable) engine;
          Object result;
           invocable.invokeFunction("myFunction", "value");
         
          } catch (FileNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Perhaps remove the space after function `YamlToJson = function(name)`

Comment: this seems to be an issue with your javascript syntax, I don't see a direct relation to java

Comment: @Stultuske more likely a problem with the ScriptEngineManager parser so yes JAVA

Comment: `var fs = require('fs'),`  looks like your trying to run `node.js` code, does ScriptEngineManager (nashorn) support this?

Comment: Usually Java evaluates JavaScripts in a browser sandbox, thus has no access to the file system by default. I think the problem is there, try removing any dependency to `fs`, then try convert your code to ES5, and see if in a way or another you get an output

Comment: Maybe an line-ending issue?

Comment: Maybe it's caused by the arrow function